# How to send a request using Telegram API

Tags: java, api, telegram

I'm learning to use the Telegram client api (not the bot api). I'm currently trying out simple things to try to understand how things work. I'm currently trying to retrieve information about a channel but not managing to.

From what I searched, there's very little documentation, examples and no tutorials. If you possibly know of tutorials, I would be very thankful if you shared them with me.

Method I'm using to retrieve info:

```java
    public static void printChatInfo(int chatId) {
        try {
            TLRequestChannelsGetChannels request = new TLRequestChannelsGetChannels();
            TLIntVector ints = new TLIntVector();
            ints.add(chatId);
            request.setId(ints);
            TLVector<TLAbsChat> chats = bot.getKernelComm().doRpcCallSync(request).getChats();
            for (TLAbsChat chat : chats) {
                System.out.println("*****************************" +
                        "\n*****************************" +
                        "\n*****************************" +
                        "\n*****************************" +
                        "\n*****************************");
                System.out.println(chat.getId());
                if (chat instanceof TLChat) {
                    TLChat chatCast = (TLChat) chat;
                    System.out.println(chatCast.getTitle());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("NOT INSTANCE");
                }
                System.out.println("*****************************" +
                        "\n*****************************" +
                        "\n*****************************" +
                        "\n*****************************" +
                        "\n*****************************");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Where it's being called:

```java
    public void onTLMessage(TLMessage message) {
        final TLAbsPeer absPeer = message.getToId();
        System.out.println(message.getMessage());
        Deepthought.printChatInfo(message.getChatId());
        if (absPeer instanceof TLPeerUser) {
            onTLMessageForUser(message);
        } else {
            BotLogger.severe(LOGTAG, "Unsupported Peer: " + absPeer.toString());
        }
    }
```

`System.out.println(message.getMessage());` is working correctly.

The exceptions at `TLVector<TLAbsChat> chats = bot.getKernelComm().doRpcCallSync(request).getChats();`:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.telegram.api.engine.RpcException: INPUT_CONSTRUCTOR_INVALID_04A42D7B
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.telegram.bot.kernel.KernelComm.doRpcCallSync(KernelComm.java:185)
    at org.telegram.Deepthought.printChatInfo(Deepthought.java:97)
    at org.telegram.plugins.echo.handlers.TLMessageHandler.onTLMessage(TLMessageHandler.java:30)
    at org.telegram.plugins.echo.CustomUpdatesHandler.onTLMessage(CustomUpdatesHandler.java:98)
    at org.telegram.plugins.echo.CustomUpdatesHandler.onTLAbsMessageCustom(CustomUpdatesHandler.java:74)
    at org.telegram.plugins.echo.CustomUpdatesHandler.onTLUpdateNewMessageCustom(CustomUpdatesHandler.java:67)
    at org.telegram.bot.handlers.UpdatesHandlerBase.onTLUpdateNewMessage(UpdatesHandlerBase.java:327)
    at org.telegram.bot.handlers.UpdatesHandlerBase.processUpdate(UpdatesHandlerBase.java:122)
    at org.telegram.bot.kernel.MainHandler$UpdateHandlerThread.run(MainHandler.java:305)
Caused by: org.telegram.api.engine.RpcException: INPUT_CONSTRUCTOR_INVALID_04A42D7B
    at org.telegram.api.engine.TelegramApi$2.onError(TelegramApi.java:345)
    at org.telegram.api.engine.TelegramApi$ProtoCallback.onRpcError(TelegramApi.java:851)
    at org.telegram.mtproto.MTProto.onMTProtoMessage(MTProto.java:375)
    at org.telegram.mtproto.MTProto.onMTMessage(MTProto.java:255)
    at org.telegram.mtproto.MTProto.access$1300(MTProto.java:44)
    at org.telegram.mtproto.MTProto$ResponseProcessor.run(MTProto.java:754)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.telegram.Deepthought.printChatInfo(Deepthought.java:97)
    at org.telegram.plugins.echo.handlers.TLMessageHandler.onTLMessage(TLMessageHandler.java:30)
    at org.telegram.plugins.echo.CustomUpdatesHandler.onTLMessage(CustomUpdatesHandler.java:98)
    at org.telegram.plugins.echo.CustomUpdatesHandler.onTLAbsMessageCustom(CustomUpdatesHandler.java:74)
    at org.telegram.plugins.echo.CustomUpdatesHandler.onTLUpdateNewMessageCustom(CustomUpdatesHandler.java:67)
    at org.telegram.bot.handlers.UpdatesHandlerBase.onTLUpdateNewMessage(UpdatesHandlerBase.java:327)
    at org.telegram.bot.handlers.UpdatesHandlerBase.processUpdate(UpdatesHandlerBase.java:122)
    at org.telegram.bot.kernel.MainHandler$UpdateHandlerThread.run(MainHandler.java:305)
```

I appreciate any ideas that might solve or help solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your client user a member of the channel already? Is the `chatId` correct?

Comment: Yes, the client is a member and I suppose the chatId is correct as it's being returned by the api.

Comment: I also searched for a method to retrieve the chat ID without using the API to confirm but it doesn't seem possible.